# python convolution without padding

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I'm looking for an easy way to implement a 2D Convolution of 2 n-dim arrays without any padding in python. 
I found the function

```
scipy.ndimage.convolve(input, weights, output=None, mode='constant', cval=0.0, origin=0)
```

which seems to do exactly what i want, but just a little bit to much. The function provides several options for padding in the border region, but as far as i know, NO option WITHOUT any padding, which makes me really wondering.

Of course it would be possible to just cut of the borders, but this seems a very unattractive solution to me and since i keep an eye on the performance of my program, it wouldn't prevent the unnecessary computations

---

edit:
i'm sorry, but i confused correlation and convolution. What I actually meant was  CORRELATION.

Comment: use `scipy.signal.convolve` with `mode='valid'`

Comment: @ Patrick Artner I think OP wants to  ignore them

Comment: @Patrick Artner the output array should just shrink

Comment: i found out, there's another issue with ndimage.convolve. it seems to flip the weights before weighting the values in the current window of the weights. i just want to "slide" the weights matrix over the input in some dimensions and element-wise weighting the values in the current "window"

Comment: then you may want to use `correlate` instead of `convolve`

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, It seems, i confused correlation and convolution. I'm currently working with CNNs and thought convolution was the term for "elemenwise weighting the kernel and the input"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from scipy import signal
sig = np.repeat([0., 1., 0.], 100)
win = signal.hann(50)
#filtered = signal.convolve(sig, win, mode='valid') / sum(win)
filtered = signal.correlate(sig, win, mode='valid') / sum(win)
print(len(sig), len(filtered))
# 300 251
plt.plot(sig)
plt.show()
plt.plot(filtered)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. that's exactly what i needed :D